# Правильность пунктуации в предложении

Tags: пунктуация

Имеется следующее предложение:

> При этом, в именительном, винительном и творительном падежах у них окончания как у существительных, а в остальных падежах – как у прилагательных.

Подскажите, правильно ли расставлены знаки препинания? На мой взгляд все логично, хотя Word так не думает, спасибо.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

При этом в именительном, винительном и творительном падежах у них окончания, как у существительных, а в остальных падежах – как у прилагательных.

Comment: спасибо вам большое)